# Issue when putting a FileSystemWatcher if explorer.exe is open

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher, explorer

For a project, I needed some `FileSystemWatcher` on directories. But I got a weird issue : after having launch the app, I can choose the directories where I want to put `FileSystemWatcher`; if the explorer.exe isn't open when I start to raise events in a directory, I can open it to do stuff in the watched directory. In this case, **handlers are fired, and all works perfectly**.

Let's imagine *I let the explorer.exe open*, and I put a `FileSystemWatcher` in another directory via my app. From this point, **I can't modify anything in this second directory** : when I modify / rename a file (there's no error during creation of files. EDIT : and I can modify the new file, change his name, etc...), Windows (note this is not the application, but the OS) throws me an error which means "the process can't access this file because of another process accessing it right now".

Does someone have any idea about this, please ?

EDIT : okay, I'm dumb. I just forgot to close a stream...

Comment: Okay, sorry guys, it was not an issue with the FileSystemWatchers... I keep looking, and I will update this post when I will find the problem.